# Max number of counts in a tparticular hour

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have a table called Orders, i want to get maximum number of orders for each day with respect to hours with following query

```
SELECT 
   trunc(created,'HH') as dated, 
   count(*) as Counts
 FROM 
   orders 
 WHERE 
   created > trunc(SYSDATE -2) 
 group by trunc(created,'HH') ORDER BY counts DESC
```

this gets the result of all hours, I want only max hour of a day e.g.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WclkJ.png)

This result looks good but now i want only rows with max number of count for a day
e.g.

```
for 12/23/2019 max number of counts is 90 for "12/23/2019 4:00:00 PM",
for 12/22/2019 max number of counts is 25 for "12/22/2019 3:00:00 PM"
```

required dataset

```
1   12/23/2019 4:00:00 PM   90
2   12/24/2019 12:00:00 PM  76
3   12/22/2019 1:00:00 PM   25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/ROW_NUMBER.html#GUID-D5A157F8-0F53-45BD-BF8C-AE79B1DB8C41) analytic function over your original query and filter the rows with number 1.

You need to partition on the day, i.e. `TRUNC(dated)` to get the correct result

```
with ord1 as (
SELECT 
   trunc(created,'HH') as dated, 
   count(*) as Counts
 FROM 
   orders 
 WHERE 
   created > trunc(SYSDATE -2) 
 group by trunc(created,'HH')
),
ord2 as (
select dated, Counts,
row_number() over (partition by trunc(dated) order by Counts desc) as rn
from ord1)
select dated, Counts
from ord2
where rn = 1
```

The advantage of using the `ROW_NUMBER` is that it correct handels ties, i.e. cases where there are more hour in a day with the same *maximal count*. The query shows only one record and you can controll with the `order by` e.g. to show the first / last hour.

Comment: Spot On!, Thank you very much.

Comment: @BabaFooka in all questions concerning `MAX` you must specify how to handle ties, i.e. in case there are more hours with a maximum count, do you want to see all of them or only one - see ma update.

Comment: Sorry sir, Its a new account and i cannot upvote and accept.

Comment: @BabaFooka understood, please work hard, that you could do so;)

Answer (score 1):

This could be the solution and in my opinion is the most trivial.

Use the [WITH clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) to make a sub query then search for the greatest value in the data set on a specific date.

```
WITH ORD AS (
        SELECT 
            trunc(created,'HH') as dated, 
            count(*) as Counts
        FROM 
            orders 
        WHERE 
            created > trunc(SYSDATE-2) 
        group by trunc(created,'HH')
    )

SELECT * 
  FROM ORD ord 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 'X' 
       FROM ORD ord1 
     WHERE trunc(ord1.dated) = trunc(ord.dated) AND ord1.Counts > ord.Counts
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `ROW_NUMBER` as following to get the desired result:

> ```
> SELECT DATED, COUNTS
> FROM (
>         SELECT
>             TRUNC(CREATED, 'HH') AS DATED,
>             COUNT(*) AS COUNTS,
>             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>                 PARTITION BY TRUNC(CREATED)
>                 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC NULLS LAST
>             ) AS RN
>         FROM ORDERS
>         WHERE CREATED > TRUNC(SYSDATE - 2)
>         GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED, 'HH'), TRUNC(CREATED)
>     )
> WHERE RN = 1
> ```

Cheers!!